# Accounts.onLogout - what user logged out?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm excited about the addition of the Accounts.onLogout() server side hook: http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogout

However I can't seem to find a way to access the user who is logging out. The PR says the onLogout hook is directly analogous to the onLogin, but I can't find the user anywhere.

```
Accounts.onLogout(function(user) {
  console.log("onLogout:", user);
  console.log(Meteor.user());
  console.log(this._userId);
  console.log(this.connection);
});
```

outputs undefined for everything.

How can I know which user is logging out?

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out, there doesn't seem to be a way to directly access the logged out user from within the callback since `this` is `undefined` and no arguments are given to the callback.

To solve the issue I suggest you create a custom method that takes an argument: the user ID. You can simply call that method from the client code just before calling `Meteor.logout()`. Inside the method you then have access to the user ID and can lookup the user from the Database and perform whatever action you want.

### Example

```
// On the server
Meteor.methods({
  preLogoutHook: function (userId) {
    check(userId, String);
    // .. do stuff ..
  }
});

// On the client, probably in an event handler of a logout button
Meteor.call('preLogoutHook', Meteor.userId(), (error, result) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);
});
Meteor.logout();
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but worth noting that if you're being logged out reactively (e.g. your login tokens get deleted and meteor automatically logs you out), the preLogoutHook won't run.

Answer (score 0):

seems like no way to do this using onLogout function as of now,

I would not recommending tracking logout in Client code - hard to maintain this code.

Have you tried this package: [Event-Hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/differential/event-hooks)(https://atmospherejs.com/differential/event-hooks)?

> Hooks.onLoggedOut = function (userId) { ... } ( anywhere ) - Provide a callback to run when a user has logged out